# Saving file in NodeJS without using Express

Tags: node.js, file

I am working on server app that is implemented in NodeJS. As its already implemented by some one few years back, they didn't integrate Express JS. I've to include the functionality of receiving images/files from the web app. Is it possible to accept file functionality in NodeJS without using Express. 
There are some frameworks like muller that can works efficiently with Express+Node. I'm looking for something that can work without Express.

Answer (score 1):

`multer` internally uses [`busboy`](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy), which can be used without Express.

Its [example code](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy#examples) shows you how to use it using Node's built-in `http/https` module.